# xlsx-js SheetJS cell styling

Tags: javascript, xlsx, sheetjs

Cell styling not working properly when exporting to SheetJS.

**my code**

[image]

**result i want**

[image]

**actual result**

[image]

I don't know why the text is hidden.

I want the text to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've added a value to cell C2. Excel will automatically hide overflowing values from one cell if there's a value in the next cell over. Try removing the value from C2; I'm not familiar with SheetJS so you may have to insert `null` or `undefined` rather than an empty string or just deleting `v`.

Comment: If you insert null or undefined rather than empty string or delete v
Styling doesn't work.